# Pytest-style fixture dependencies in Java

Tags: java, testing, junit

After spending some time away from java, where I used python's great [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org) framework, I got used to the functionality of setting up and tearing down test environments via chains (or rather graphs) of fixtures.

For those unfamiliar, a typical use case would be a base fixture that creates a self-reverting database transaction, then inheriting that fixture to insert some test data, and so on.
One would then require one or more fixtures on a per-test basis. This allows for a very concise setup of test environments, as opposed to `setUp` and `tearDown` methods found in most testing frameworks.

Coming back to java, I'm not sure how something like this can be implemented in JUnit for example, or if an analogous framework exists.